# Is there any way to extract metadata from MPEG TS file or HLS live stream

Tags: android

I have a requirement where i need to extract the ID3 tags or meta data from HLS live stream or MPEG TS file .
I have an idea of reading the Id3 tags and extracting them using internal buffers,but i dont know how to implement this idea

So Please let me know any sample/example code or idea for extracting metadata from MPEG TS File or HLS stream in Android

Answer (score 0):

Hey it is very late reply. But it might be helpful to you. Try like this

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH);//MEDIA_PATH is your http path of mpeg ts file
for (i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
                MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
                String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
                /*if (mime.startsWith("audio/")) {
                    extractor.selectTrack(i);
                    decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);

                    if(decoder != null)
                    {
                        decoder.configure(format, null  /*surface*/ , null  /*crypto*/ , 0  /*flags*/ );
                    }

                    break;
                }*/ //this commented code may not useful for you. If you wanna you can use..
            }
```